# CNN model accuracy is not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have many time series data (time & voltage) from different devices. I was trying to convert this time series data to an image array so that it can be used as an image and I can apply CNN on the image and can classify from which device the data came from. It is based on assumption that different device produces different voltage signature which should be differentiable. I applied a function that split the time series data to an image array and then used CNN to classify. The image size is 14x100 pixel. The problem is the accuracy of the model is not changing or it is barely changing. Please find the complete coding below

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay, confusion_matrix

#Reading data from directory
import pathlib
data_dir = ('Test')
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

#File name dictionary
file_name_dict = {
    'Device_1' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_1/*.csv')),
    'Device_2' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_2/*.csv')),
    'Device_3' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_3/*.csv')),
    'Device_4' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_4/*.csv')),
    'Device_5' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_5/*.csv')),
    'Device_6' : list(data_dir.glob('Device_6/*.csv'))
}

#File label dictionary
file_label_dict = {
    'Device_1' : 0,
    'Device_2' : 1,
    'Device_3' : 2,
    'Device_4' : 3,
    'Device_5' : 4,
    'Device_6' : 5,
}


#Processing and labelling the data

device_list, device_label = [],[]   #compressed

#Reading each file, replacing original value with moving average value
for device_name, folder in file_name_dict.items():
    for file in folder:
        file_df = pd.read_csv(str(file))
        file_df.columns = ['time', 'voltage']
        file_df['MA'] = file_df['voltage'].rolling(10,min_periods=0).mean()# moving average
        file_df= file_df.drop('voltage',axis=1)
        file_df.rename(columns={'MA':'voltage'},inplace=True)
        
        #Applying a function
        threshold = file_df['voltage'].diff().gt(1)
        group = (threshold&~threshold.shift(fill_value=False)).cumsum().add(1)
        time= lambda i: i['time'].groupby(group).apply(lambda j: j- j.iloc[0])
        df_2 = (file_df.assign(bit=group,time=time).pivot(index='bit', columns='time', values='voltage'))

        df_3 = df_2.copy()
        df_3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_3 = df_3.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

        #Compressing to  14 rows 100 columns
        df_4=df_3.iloc[:10, :100]
        
        #Filling out null values
        df_4= df_4.fillna(method='pad')
        
        #Saving each dataframe to a list
        device_list.append(df_4)
        device_label.append(file_label_dict[device_name])
        
#Converting to numpy array
X = np.array(device_list)
y = np.array(device_label)


#Train test split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 0.30,random_state=42)

#Adding 1 dimension to make it, two dimension, to use Conv2D
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],X_test.shape[2],1)

#scaling data from 0 to 1
X_train_scaled = X_train/36 #Max voltage value 36
X_test_scaled = X_test/36

#Building a CNN a model
#Set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)
model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same", activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal',
                           input_shape=(X_train_scaled[0].shape)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
    
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6,3, padding="same", activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal',),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(12,3, padding="same",activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal',),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2),
    
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(72,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='normal',),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation= 'softmax') #Output layer

])
model_2.summary()

#Training
from tensorflow import keras
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model_2.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics= ['accuracy'])

             
history= model_2.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train,batch_size= 128 , epochs=200,validation_split=0.20, verbose=1) 
history

#Test
loss, accuracy= model_2.evaluate(X_test_scaled, y_test)
print(f'Loss: {loss}, Accuracy: {accuracy}')
print('Test accuracy : ',accuracy*100,'%')
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

The accuracy starts from 0.16 and goes up to 0.18, not going above 0.18. I tried to change different parameters of the CNN model like adding more convolutional layer, dense layer, changing the learning rate of the adam optimizer, using different optimizer, tried with different batch_size but the accuracy of the model is not improving at all.

I am just confused if I have done something wrong during processing of the data. Could someone please look at the coding and tell me the way I labeled the data is OK, or there is something wrong with my coding. If the code is fine, any suggestion on how can I improve the accuracy is much appreciated. I am just not sure if it a coding problem or there is any problem with the model or the data is not good enough for classification task.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that your label can be inferred from your data? If yes, how did you come up with the architecture? CNN can be used for time series but you most likely want to use Conv1D instead. Once you have theoretical ground for your architecture, you might want to start with a much smaller one and increase its size later on. Other relevant questions: how much data point? is the input data normalized/decorrelated?

Comment: I am sorry I having difficulty to understand your question. I am not really much experienced in machine learning. I didn't understand your first question. Could you please phrase it differently? About the data point, I have 500 csv files from each devices and total 6 devices which makes it total 3000 csv files. But I have taken only 100 files from each device, total 600 files. To normalize the data I have replaced the voltage values with moving average values to remove some noise, applied a function to split the curves. If you look at the coding you can see it.

Comment: Can your data predict the label? For example, to predict the weather, it is useful to have some atmospheric data. It is not useful to know what you had for lunch. Conclusion: weather forecasts can be inferred from atmospheric data. Weather forecasts cannot be inferred from your last lunch.

Comment: @qmeeus I guess, what I am trying to do, needs a little bit of explanation. I only have voltage over time data. I want to use those voltage value as pixel value and train a CNN model that will predict from which device the data is coming from. Please have a look at the image here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv7vp.png . I used a function to split the curve. After split the data looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Pix.png this array corresponds to grayscale value of an image. So my input is this voltage value and output is the device name from which the data has been generated.

Comment: @qmeeus I trained my model with the data from different devices and trying to predict which device generated the data. Since my input is voltage value and output is device name, so I guess my model should be able to predict the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the learning rate to 0.001 solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

CNNs are usually used for spatial relations between the data (as you said, e.g. images) but it seems, that your data doesn't have this kind of spatial relation. Instead, you describe them as time series and for time series, it's common to use so-called recurrent neural networks (RNN). They take as input one step of a time series and transport a hidden state to the next step additionally to the next time series step. Maybe this kind of models fit better to your needs.

Comment: I would like to run this project on Google coral or Nvidia jetson nano and I have been told that they can only run CNN, so by the device I am constrained to use CNN. The purpose is to find out whether CNN can be used to classify the device from which the data is coming from.

Comment: @Nazmul1001 I don't know why an LSTM shouldn't run on Nvidia Jetson nano. I did instance segmentation only on jetson Nanos so far, so I can't tell from my experience. But you are running a Linux-based OS and all the TensorFlow libraries are available, and from the hardware side, there is nothing special needed for LSTMs. You can give it a try to generate a model based on LSTM and see if the losses are decreasing. After that, you can try to run it on Jetson Nano. But we managed to run YoloV4 on a nano, I bet that it can handle - even larger - LSTM-NNs as well.